# Does $p(a)=q(a)$ for all polynomials $p,q$ that coincide on the spectrum of $a$ imply that $a$ is normal?

Tags: c-star-algebras, functional-calculus

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-Algebra and $a\in A$. Assume that $p(a)=q(a)$ for all formal complex polynomials $p(X),q(X)$ that coincide as functions on the spectrum of $a$. Does this imply that $a$ is normal?

The converse is certainly true by the continuous functional calculus.
In case this is true, I'm also interested if this holds in $*$-Algebras or Banach-$*$-Algebras.

Comment: It may be useful to note that holomorphic functional calculus will suffice to handle complex polynomials

Comment: The $a=bcb^{-1}$ approach seems reasonable, I'll check your example later, so don't worry when I don't check your answer yet ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not.  At the very least, it suffices for $a$ to be *similar* to a normal matrix.  That is, we may have that $a = bcb^{-1}$, where $c$ is normal.

For instance, take $A = \Bbb C^{2 \times 2}$, and 
$$
a = \pmatrix{2&1\\0&1}
$$
Over finite dimensional $C^*$-algebras, $p(a) = q(a)$ for all complex polynomials that coincide on the spectrum will imply that $a$ is diagonalizable, which is to say that $a$ is similar to some normal element.  I am not sure whether the same will hold true in general.

Comment: Summarizing this for myself: I see that if $a=bcb^{-1}$ for normal $c$, we have $p(a)=p(bcb^{-1})=bp(c)b^{-1}=bq(c)b^{-1}=q(a)$ in any $C^*$-Algebra where $p,q$ coincide on the spectrum of $a$, which is the spectrum of $c$, by using continuous functional calculus for $p(c)=q(c)$. So the $p(a)=q(a)$ part is true for all $a$ similar to a normal $C^*$-algebra element. This class is strictly greater than the class of normal elements, as your example shows ($a$ being not normal, but diagonizable with eigenvectors $(1,0)$ and $(1,-1)$).

Comment: In fact for $A=\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, the following are equivalent for alle $a\in A$: (1) $a$ is similar to a normal matrix, (2) $p(a)=0$ for all polynomials that vanish on the spectrum of $a$. The implication $(1)\Rightarrow(2)$ was shown above, so suppose (2). Let $p(X)=\prod_i (X-\lambda_i)$ for all unique eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k$. Then $p$ vanishes on the spectrum of $a$, hence $p(a)=0$ by assumption, hence the minimal polynomial $\mu_a$ divides $p$, so $p=\mu_a$. That means the Jordan Normal form $J_a$ of $a$ is diagonal, so $a$ is similar to the normal matrix $J_a$.

Comment: Since any finite dimensional unital $C^*$-algebra is isomorphic to some $\oplus_{i=1}^k \mathbb{C}^{n_i\times n_i}$ (found this in the Wikipedia $C^*$-algebra article), the equivalence generalizes from $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ to any finite dimensional unital $C^*$-algebra.